# Reverse Url from slug with Persian or arabic languages in Django

Tags: python, html, django

hi i want to reverse url from slug 
in model i have slug :

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
```

and for get absolute url :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])
```

and in settings.urls :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
```

and in shop.urls :

```
app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

and value for my slug is :

```
slug="گالری-شلوار"
```

now i get error :

```
Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '('گالری-شلوار',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Comment: i Should Use re-path instead path  and it's work... but it is very hard for me to find regex expression   ( re_path(r'(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
now i want a simple way to solving this problem without regex

Answer (score 2):

For arabic letter you must open url encoder. You can do this with add this code to your `settings.py` file

```
ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse anything you must first make it string by

Now we can reverse the string

```
x = 'Hello World!'
for i in x:
    x = x[::-1]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?